# Returning lvalue reference causes a closure?

Tags: c++11

I'm learning about lvalue/rvalue and there is an example about lvalue:

```
int& foo();
foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
```

Normally people will let foo() return a global variable or a static varible inside its body, but if we define a local variable inside foo's body, it also works (with warning: *reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'i' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]*):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int &foo(){int i=7; return i;};

int main() {

    foo() = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

Why this is allowed in C++, is it a closure?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

It's pointless to return a reference to a local variable - any use of such a reference by the caller is undefined, since the local variable is necessarily destroyed by that time.